# Ambiguity in Declaration of singleton tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I declared a list inside a tuple like this,

`a = ([x,y])`

Now for accessing the first element `x`of the inner list I assumed we would have to use, `a[1][1]` .

But it gives an error of out of bounds and we can access the element simply like `a[1]`

Does this mean singleton tuple can also be declared like `a([temp])` along with the usual `a(temp,)`? Or is it treated simply  as a list?

How does python implement this? I could not find any concrete explanation or documentation.

Comment: It's not a tuple, just a list; without the comma the parentheses make no difference.

Comment: Thanks i got confused as i found another answer that said tuples can also be declared like `tuple(['temp'])`, In which tuple is actually the inbuilt function which skipped my mind.